# Contact form 7: разметка и стили - работают, а скрипты - нет

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7

В дочерней теме создал форму с помощью `Contact Form 7`. Не срабатывает ajax, страница перезагружается после нажатия на кнопку, никакой валидации, никаких уведомлений об ошибках или успешной отправки, никаких писем на почту не приходит.

Но! Форма работает в родительской теме.

Для полноты ещё следует сказать, что такая же проблема была в одном из предыдущих проектов. Если вставлял шорткод в .php-файл, то форма не работала корректно. Проблема решилась после того, как вставил шорткод через визуальный редактор.

Comment: Приведите вопрос в читаемый вид. "...стили - работают, а стили нет". "Форма работает в родительской форме". То, что вы написали, иначе как белиберда, классифицировать невозможно. Имейте уважение к тем, кто читает ваш вопрос.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, исправил. Спасибо!

Comment: Остался пазл "Форма работает в родительской форме."

Comment: Похоже, что в дочерней теме запрещён REST API. Или ошибка своих скриптов (а что в консоли браузера?) и js валится ещё до запуска скриптов cf7.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил сменой плагина на Ninja Form